# Entity Framework modify existing migration script to set the existing date column default date

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can anyone please help me how to change an existing migration script using Entity Framework as the ORM, so that I can set a default date to a property of type datetime?

I created a new datetime property and changed the migration script. Then it works fine. But I would like to change the existing property without creating a new datetime property.

My migration script in case I add a new datetime property:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("Payment.PaymentCardTransaction", "CreatedDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"));
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropColumn("Payment.PaymentCardTransaction", "CreatedDate");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something here, but it sounds as simple as adding a new migration and then use the AlterColumn function which has the same definition as AddColumn.

```
AlterColumn("Payment.PaymentCardTransaction", "CreatedDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the new migration script will be added only when i change the model class right? right now, the script is generated automatically. how do i create a new script?

Comment: Running Add-Migration from the package manager console will generate a new migration for you even if there is no changes. In the event of no changes it will just have empty Up and Down methods

Comment: You are right. I added an empty add-migration from console and added the following:     public partial class DefaultDatePaymentCardTransaction : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AlterColumn("Payment.PaymentCardTransaction", "DateCreated", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            AlterColumn("Payment.PaymentCardTransaction", "DateCreated", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class DefaultDatePaymentCardTransaction : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("Payment.PaymentCardTransaction", "DateCreated", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("Payment.PaymentCardTransaction", "DateCreated", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that just excluding the defaultValueSql parameter doesn't likely remove the default value. I would set it to an empty string personally and depending on what the constraints were previously you might want to change nullable to true as well.